# Microsoft.ApplicationServer.HttpEnhancements reference missing

Tags: reference, visual-studio-2012

I have opened a sample project where the highlighted reference is missing. I cannot find this reference in .net assemblies, and have had no luck googling it. Is this .net native or a third party API assembly?

[image]

Please help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assembly is provided by WebApi tools ( exactly the webapi.enhacements package) and you could get this assembly (and others) with nuget just by running this command:

```
Install-Package WebApi.Enhancements -Version 0.6.0
```

More info [here](http://nuget.org/packages/WebApi.Enhancements).

Comment: perfect, thanks @jtorres. Thats exactly solution need to install. Note: there was an issue during installation of package because of solution path too long, so moving the solution into a directory having small physical path resolved that.